# ExpandableListView, how to limit the child range minimum to 1 [0 in case of no item]

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show one child (0 in case of no item) in collapse state of ExpandableListView. Android is giving `collapseGroup` but it collapse all the item. i want to collapse the child with the exception of one element.

Any clue or help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of showing one item (or null if empty) instead none when **ExpandableListView** child group is collapsed on `collapseGroup` one has to implements his own ExpandableListView related to custom **ExpandableListConnector** realization with "overriden" `collapseGroup` and `expandGroup` methods. For example `collapseGroup` has to be:

```
 boolean collapseGroup(int groupPos) {
     ExpandableListPosition elGroupPos = ExpandableListPosition.obtain(
             ExpandableListPosition.GROUP, groupPos, -1, -1);
     PositionMetadata pm = getFlattenedPos(elGroupPos);
     elGroupPos.recycle();
     // Group will be collapsed until there will be presented 1 or null items
     if (pm == null && mExpGroupMetadataList.size() <= 1) return false;

     boolean retValue = collapseGroup(pm);
     pm.recycle();
     return retValue;
 }

 boolean collapseGroup(PositionMetadata posMetadata) {
     /*
      * Collapsing requires removal from mExpGroupMetadataList 
      */

     /*
      * If it is null, it must be already collapsed. This group metadata
      * object should have been set from the search that returned the
      * position metadata object.
      */
     // Group will be collapsed until there will be presented 1 or null items
     if (posMetadata.groupMetadata == null && mExpGroupMetadataList.size() <= 1) return false;

     // Remove the group from the list of expanded groups 
     mExpGroupMetadataList.remove(posMetadata.groupMetadata);

     // Refresh the metadata
     refreshExpGroupMetadataList(false, false);

     // Notify of change
     notifyDataSetChanged();

     // Give the callback
     mExpandableListAdapter.onGroupCollapsed(posMetadata.groupMetadata.gPos);

     return true;
 }
```

Similar logic has to be implemented for `expandGroup`.

Comment: Thanks friend for quite a impressive answer but i am having problem in using the ExpandableListPosition and PositionMetadata  classes in my code